# Are "exotic" (package) tags useful?

Tags: discussion, tagging, etiquette

Yesterday, a question was asked about [Numbering figures and tables by their section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/numbering-figures-and-tables-in-listoffigures-listoftables-by-their-section). My answer, which was accepted, used the [chngcntr](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) package which allows to change the resetting of counters. I had answered a [similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10448/continuous-footnote-numbering) question some time ago, so I decided to a) provide a link to the old question b) create a new [chngcntr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chngcntr) tag so that potential future questioners would (hopefully) easier find the answers to their "counter-resetting" questions.

I admit that I should have created a tag wiki excerpt right then, as [chngcntr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chngcntr) is sort of "exhibit A" for an undecipherable tag name. But besides that -- and because of [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/921027#921027) chat comment by Andrew Stacey --, I'm starting to wonder about the usefulness of such "exotic" package tags. Is there a lower threshold of the number of affected questions that should be respected before new tags are created? (Obviously, a tag that is used only once doesn't make sense.) Which other factors, if any, should be taken into account?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm personally in favor of tagging *questions* which reference to a certain package with the appropriate package tag. However, tagging the question with the package tag used in one/the accepted answer is a whole different thing. The tags are for questions not for solutions. Now, I can understand the argument that the question is then found easier, but not in the highlighted case of "exotic" package tags which no one would use in a search expression.

A question might be better tagged with a general tag, e.g. if it is a "counter-resetting" question it should be tagged with [counter-resetting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-resetting) (TODO: find better name) instead. Only questions about the `chngcntr` package should be tagged with [chngcntr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chngcntr) then.

Comment: Actually the fact that a specific package *will* be found in a search reduces the need for a specific tag for it anyway.  If you *are* interested in a particular package, you can find answers or questions that involve it quite easily.

Comment: @Martin: In the example question, I felt that {numbering} was the general tag. (Which brings up another tagging question: When should one use {numbering} vs. {counters}?)

Comment: @lockstep I think that `counters` is a more specific tag than `numbering` but should be used in addition to `numbering` when the question explicitly asks about a counter or asks about macro writing involving counters.

Comment: @Alan: Good suggestion! At the moment, of the 31 questions tagged with {counters}, only three also feature {numbering}, which makes me think that {counters} is rather used as a replacement for {numbering}.

Comment: @lockstep I think the choice of `counters` vs. `numbering` may also reflect the questioner's latex experience. If you know that numbering is done with counters, you may use counters, but if you don't, you presumably won't.

Comment: @Alan: That's why I created a {counters} tag wiki excerpt stating that {numbering} is the more general tag.

Comment: I agree with this, and people should be reminded that tags are *not* a replacement for search -- and in fact they work brilliantly together, to search within a broader tag for some very narrow term that appears in the question or answer body.

Answer (score 5):

I think this question is related to this question: [Adding tags to a question in accordance with a provided answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/577/2693). Package tags make sense when people ask questions about packages. No one has asked a question about the `chngcntr` package, although many answers involving changing counter dependencies will use it.

So to me, package tags (whether exotic or not) should only be created in response to questions that ask about them.

In this particular case, if we have a `counters` tag, that should suffice.

Comment: Suppose a package tag has been created in response to questions involving this particular package. Would it be admissible in your opinion to add such a tag to other questions where the accepted answer used this package? (I'm thinking about {biblatex} and {titlesec}.)

Comment: Although I see the logic in adding tags that reflect (accepted) answers, I'm generally not in favour of them, for the reasons that Jukka notes in his response to your question. Tags really should be reflections of the question, not the answers.  For example, in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9652/2693) the accepted answer (and most upvoted) is the TikZ one, but this simply reflects the popularity of TikZ on the site and by the questioner.  So adding TikZ as a tag to this question seems just wrong.

Comment: There, the answers created a sort of "TikZ vs. pstricks vs. others" showcase, which is sort of a special case. (BTW, the appropriate general tag was {diagrams}, not {graphics}.)

Comment: @lockstep Sure, I agree that that's the extreme case, but that's really the point. Tagging based on the answer leads to making such decisions. For example, sometimes the accepted answer isn't necessarily the best answer even if it works, so adding a tag based on the accepted answer in those cases would also be problematic IMO.