# What's the policy on retagging questions based on answers?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I was wondering if a policy exists (and if so, what it is) for retagging questions once they have been answered. To illustrate what I mean, I recently answered 
[Draw small cross at the center of the page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32948/draw-small-cross-at-the-center-of-the-page/32950#32950). It is currently tagged as [technical-drawing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-drawing), perhaps the [positioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/positioning) tag would have been better, but that is not the point I want to make here. The answer I provided (which was accepted) was a pure [TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) answer. Should the [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) tag be added to the question based on the accepted answer?

Additionally, @ThorstenDonig provided an answer using [`eso-pic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) which is also perfectly acceptable. So should we also add the [eso-pic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eso-pic) tag in this case?

I suppose in part this question is about why are questions tagged a certain way? To make it easier for people with significant knowledge in a certain area to find the questions in order to answer them? Or also for people with a general interest in an area to find the questions? If the former is the case, tagging after a question has been answered has little use, in case of the latter it could still be valuable.

Comment: I fully support Roelof Spijker view, and also his arguments for why re-tagging also shall be based on the answers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In general, tags are supposed to be about questions, not answers. So the [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) tag should be used if the question mentions or implies Tikz, but not if the answers do.

Comment: So does this mean the (primary) reason for tagging is to guide people to questions in order to answer them? Or is that too strong a conclusion?

Comment: @wh1t3 Tags are there to help people searching the site and also so that it's possible to 'watch' particular topics.

Comment: Well, the possibility to 'watch' topics was my main motivation for asking this question. My main interest is in TikZ and therefore I subscripte to the [tag:tikz-pgf] tag. However, [some answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/onlyitems-how-to-select-specific-items-from-an-item-list/32611#32611) are completely relevant to this tag and interesting to me, though the question is not in any way related to TikZ. If not trough retagging the question, is there any other way to make at least these answers appear to the followers of relevant tags? (ctd)

Comment: (...) The possibility to tag answers seems interesting to me. I don't know whether this is something that is technically possible or even desired by the rest of the community. I suppose I am mainly interested in the opinion of others and whether or not there is a good way for me to become aware of these kinds of answers without having to sift through all the questions on topics not directly interesting to me.

Comment: @wh1t3: I've heard that it is possible to set up a "smart search" that has an RSS feed so that you get automatic notifications.  You could set one up for `\usepackage{tikz}`.  (Before you ask, I don't know how to do this, I'm just aware of the possibility.)

Comment: @AndrewStacey: I had a look and according to [Jeff's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5857/rss-feed-for-searches/8055#8055) on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5857/rss-feed-for-searches) it isn't possible. However a different answer to the same question suggests [feed43](http://www.feed43.com) as a service to set this up, which is what I have done. So now I have a feed of the latests posts (questions and answers) that have `tikz` in the body and aren't closed [right here](http://www.feed43.com/newesttikz.xml) if anybody else is interested.

Comment: I'd really love tagging answers

Answer (score 17):

I agree fully with Joseph's answer. Tags are about the question, not the answers.

Questions should be retagged if the OP used the wrong tag, forgot one or it turned out to be a different problem than expected. Like, he got an error while using macro `\foobar` but it is actually the `barbaz` package which causes it. Then the question should be tagged for that.

BTW, there are only five tags allowed and there could be, in theory, more than four or five different answers using different techniques. You can't give tags for all answers then. (Not that this is so likely to occur).